# What's the most distant object we've measured by parallax?

Tags: distances, parallax

[The openstax Astronomy textbook](https://openstax.org/books/astronomy/pages/19-4-the-h-r-diagram-and-cosmic-distances#fs-id1165720742736) says that when the Gaia mission is complete, we'll have parallax measurements to 30k light years. Do we have those now?

What's the most distant object astronomers have measured by parallax so far?

Comment: Similar question here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/19666/24157

Comment: Different but related [What is the maximum distance *measurable* with parallax?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/31711/7982)